# Function/Operator in Dart to obtain size of a data type

Tags: dart

I wish to know the amount of memory allocated to different data types in Dart. But I cannot find a function/operator (for instance the `sizeof` operator in C) to do so. I've referred the `dart:core` library for this purpose, but still couldn't find any appropriate method. So, is there any other way to obtain the size of a data type OR is it just unobtainable?

Comment: Why you would need to get the size of  a datatype in Dart?

Comment: Are you asking about a specific data type or just a generalized `sizeof` type operation?

Comment: I'm expecting availability of generalized function/operator. I wish to know about such a feature for mainly 2 reasons : i. Curiosity ii. To make economical choices with regards to selection of data types (for instance, if I've to simply store and display a numerical value, then should I be using `int` or `String` data type?)

Comment: @Argon While I definitely support the satisfaction of curiosity, trying to figure out the size of data types so you can make "economical decisions" is a recipe for disaster as far as your productivity is concerned. In high-level languages, the decision to use the smallest data type possible should always come second to making your code readable and expressive, your modules decoupled and flexible, and your program architecture robust and organized. Don't worry about micro-optimizations like this unless you've actually confirmed that it is a significant and tangible issue if your app.

Comment: @Argon Also FWIW, you should always use a numerical type to store a numerical value. A `String` will always take up more space (how much more depends on the runtime), and it makes handling and manipulating the number way more complicated than it needs to be. Don't convert the number to a `String` until the last possible moment (i.e. as you're giving it to a widget to display). There's a micro-optimization, and then there's code smell - ignore micro-optimizations if you can help it, but always strive to eliminate code smell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not really make much sense to have such an operator in a high-level programming language like Dart where the size of types can change by optimization on runtime and based on if fields in classes are used or not. If you need the size of a given type for debug purposely, I guess you can find some information by using the Dart Observatory:

https://dart-lang.github.io/observatory/

If the size of data is important on runtime, then use the `dart:typed_data` library where you have access to types there are documented with a specific size. E.g. `Int8List` which is documented as:

> A fixed-length list of 8-bit signed integers.

And if you need to have the size because of programming against native libraries, there are in fact a `sizeOf` method in the new `dart:ffi` library which can only be used on the types in `dart:ffi`:

https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.1/dart-ffi/sizeOf.html

Comment: i do not agree with this, what if I want to log my http headers size in bytes or the response I got in bytes? this is where i am stuck at.

Comment: @shivzuh Your HTTP headers and HTTP packages does contain a length which we can measure in bytes. This has really nothing to do with the size of different datatypes since we are always going to send HTTP content as String in some kind of encoding. Your are not going to send a 64 bit integer over HTTP and need to know it takes 8 bytes to send. You are instead sending the number as text where the length are defined by the number of digits.

Comment: @shivzuh But it sounds like you do have an entire different question in mind. Please make a new question about that problem and provide a minimal working example showing your problem. Then I am sure some people are going to help you.

Comment: thank you for the comment, nice points actually, it helped me rationalize something but, im using dio and dio does not give you the size in bytes unfourtanely. this is why im sad, no need to make a question because ive looked at other sources and my needs are impossible to achieve as of now with dio

Comment: @shivzuh Ok, if you say so. What I can see from the dio package it is possible to get some informations about e.g. the size of the body and maybe the headers. But I don't know your problem in details and what you want which is why I suggested you to create a question. I am just puzzled why you thought a sizeof operator (which this question is about) would solve anything related to your problem which is why I also think you still don't have the full understanding about your problem area and can therefore not conclude something is impossible (yet). :)

Comment: @julemand101 here is the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66665021/firebase-performance-with-dio

Comment: @shivzuh Ok. I will take a look at it after some sleep. It is 0:43 here in Denmark :)

Comment: I want to know the size of the objects because I am using Firebase and it has a limit of size per document. Of course, I could divide the document into collections with documents, but it is some data that is changing all the time so it becomes really expensive. In my case, most of the time it will fit in one document, but as user data grows it might become the size of two or three documents.

Comment: @HyungTaeCarapetoFigur The problem is how we are saving data in Firebase and the differences in how we determine the size of something. E.g. I can see a text field in a Firebase document is encoded as UTF-8. But Dart are using UTF-16 internally for `String`. So what should a given `sizeof` operation measure here? The current question here want to know how much memory a given object takes on the machine (let's just ignore object overheads for now). You want to know how much space a object would take converted to a Firebase object. This two numbers are going to be quite different.

Comment: @julemand101 I see... Well, Firebase Firestore has a JSON-like format, so I believe a function that measures JSON string sizes already would be a good approximation. But I think in the end I will make a limit like 1000 map properties in the document or something...