# How to get the size of an dart object in bytes

Tags: database, flutter, dart

I'm doing a database comparison, I'm measuring how much time does it take to insert different objects into a database. I need to know the size of an object in bytes. I think the closest function is **sizeOf()** but I don't know how to use it. Does anyone know how to measure/get the object size in bytes? Thank you in advance

Comment: Your database are not going to save your Dart objects in a raw format similar to how they are stored in memory. Instead, you are going to use different data types for each field where each type have its own size requirement (some depending on the data like e.g. `String`).

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60135399/function-operator-in-dart-to-obtain-size-of-a-data-type